# Lua attempt to index a nil value on click script

Tags: lua

Im realy not that deep in Lua and im very bad in learining something "out of the box" so i mostly try around and get something out of it. Currently im working on something like a interface modification for a common video game.

Overall it is very simple. In the tool i use i can weite down lua scripts with different events. The event i want to use is on click. I got two pictures. One is the button that enables the enlarged space and the other one is the enlarged space. THe script is working so far but i get a lua error.

This is the script:

```
if pressed then
kgPanels:FetchFrame("stance_closed"):Show()
kgPanels:FetchFrame("stance_open"):Hide()
end
```

It is working so far i can click on both of them and they are jumping around as expected. This is the lua error. (basicly two)

```
7x <string>:"stance_closed_OnClickDown":3: attempt to index a nil value
<string>:"stance_closed_OnClickDown":3: in function                                                  
<string>:"stance_closed_OnClickDown":1

Locals:
```

---

```
7x <string>:"stance_open_OnClickDown":2: attempt to index a nil value
<string>:"stance_open_OnClickDown":2: in function 
<string>:"stance_open_OnClickDown":1

Locals:
```

Comment: Is that snippet of lua code the `stance_closed_OnClickDown` function? Are you certain both of those frames will exist at all times?

Comment: Im not sure about it. The snippet is basicly the whole code. "stance_closed" and "stance_open" are the names of the two .tga pictures that should be visible / invisible depending on what you click. By default they are visible all the time ill upload some pictures to make it a bit easyer to understand :) Give me some minutes.

Comment: Pictures are unlikely to help here. If that error is coming from that bit of code then that means that one of those calls to `FetchFrame` is returning `nil` instead of a frame table/object. You should handle that as a possibility to avoid that error.